# Hbase fail to create table

Tags: hbase

I started HBase using ./start-hbase.sh. I did ./hbase shell to start the shell of Hbase. The problem is that I can't create a new table.

```
$ ./hbase shell 
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.92.1, r1298924, Fri Mar  9 16:58:34 UTC 2012

hbase(main):001:0> create 'test','cf'
```

---

It stays like this forever. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the Hmaster logs for that, check the *hbase.rootdir* and *hbase.zookeeper.quorum* parameters in the hbase-site.xml file.
This generally happens when Hbase cannot connect to the Zookeeper quorum.

Comment: There are other failure modes too that just hang--for example, if you are trying to use a compression method on the table that isn't supported (though that doesn't appear to be the case here). Checking the logs is the right next step.

Answer (score 9):

Your HMaster not started.
1.Kindly check your Hmaster log. 
 If you see anything like this in your log.
`INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Waiting for dfs to exit safe mode...`
then leave hadoop from safemode by using the following command.
  `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`
2.If you see anything like localhost not accepting or zookeeper not accepting.
  Then, Kindly modify the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname file.
  *remove the line 127.0.1.1 localhost*

your /etc/hosts file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1       hadoop
192.165.1.45    hadoop  hbase
```

Your /etc/hostname file should look like this
`hadoop`

Answer (score 0):

In addition, edit `/etc/hosts` if you want to work as client connection to HBase, you must write IP and hostname.

For example, HBase is running in 192.168.xx.xx but your app is running in 192.168.xx.yy

Edit `/etc/hosts` add following lines

```
 192.168.xx.yy <hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the following command does not work

```
$ hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

then try

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode forceExit
```

This works for me!